# 32-bit IEEE single precision computer number

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

What is the decimal value of the **32-bit** IEEE single precision computer number
`10111000111001100110011001100110`?

I understand that I have to split up the binary: `1 01110001` and `11001100110011001100110`

```
1) 0 × 2^7 + 1 × 2^6 + 1 × 2^5 ...
```

And

```
2) 1+1×2^−1+1×2^−2 +0×2^−3 ...
```

I can't seem to get the final decimal result correct

Comment: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first part (a single digit) is the sign of your number (here it is a negative number); the second part is the exponent (here 01110001 is 113 but you have to substract 127 which makes -14); the last part is the mantissa (here 1.7999999523162842). The whole number is about -1.8 * 2^(-14) which is -0.00010986328125.

BUT you can't get exactly 1.8 as a binary floating point number (exactly like you can't have exactly 1/3 with decimal numbers).